# What is the best firewall/iptables management tool for multiple servers?

Tags: firewall

We are setting up iptables for each server we run, is there a nagios kind of tool that will allow us to see and manage from a central console without requiring us to get in each server and setup each and every iptables ?

If there is an open source firewall that does this I'd be glad to know. (we don't want to use webmin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My [recent question](https://serverfault.com/questions/51258/iptables-management-tools-for-large-scale-environment) on large-scale firewalling produced fwbuilder as being a possible contender -- apparently (I haven't evaluated it yet) it allows you to describe all of your firewalls in one place and then have them applied where they're needed.  Could be worth a look.

Answer (score 4):

We're looking at doing this using [Puppet](http://reductivelabs.com/products/puppet) - there's a [module](http://reductivelabs.com/trac/puppet/wiki/Recipes/ModuleIptables) for iptables configuration